# Multi-tenant Microsoft SSO in self hosted Canvas LMS

Tags: azure-active-directory, canvas-lms

I have been able to set up the single tenant SSO but don't really know what steps to follow on (Canvas or Azure side) to enable multi-tenant.

Canvas LMS is hosted on my own website.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below to convert your application into a multi-tenant app.

1. In Azure Portal, update your application registration to be multi-tenant. You can make your registration multi-tenant by finding the “Multi-Tenanted” switch on the properties page of your application registration in the Azure portal and setting it to “Yes”.
2. Update your code to send requests to the /common endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
3. Update your code to handle multiple issuer values
4. Understand user and admin consent and make appropriate code changes

More details about multi-tenant application, please refer to the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview

Comment: Can you explain 3 and 4 a bit more please. In Canvas LMS context if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not very familiar with Canvas LMS. The article below has very detailed explanations for step 3 and 4. [How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview)